# Does x86 architecture treat binary subtraction of zero/comparing with zero in a special manner?

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

While dealing with x86 assembly once again I came across a situation where I try to understand how the behavior of the cpu could be explained.

When comparing two unsigned integers with `cmp` command the state of the carry and the zero flag reflect the relation of both integers. Because `cmp` behaves like `sub` command without writing the result of the subtraction into a final register, the carry flag takes the part of the borrow flag. Furthermore, a subtraction is nothing more than the addition of the inverted value. So instead of subtracting 1, the cpu adds -1.

Now when the minuend is smaller than the subtrahend the addition during `cmp` would cause no carry but because of the needed borrow the carry flag has to be set. So you can say that the carry flag has to be inverted after the addition to get the right state.
The former assumption works for every combination of unsigned integers with one exception:

Subtracting zero from any unsigned integer is the same as adding zero to them and this does not produce a carry. So the inverted carry would result in a set carry flag which is not correct because the minuend (< 0) is bigger than the subtrahend (0) and that is why the carry flag is not allowed to be set because no borrow was needed.

I checked this behavior with a little assembly program and, of course, the cpu does not produce a set carry flag. But this is only possible if the cpu also checks for the subtrahend to be zero (and the minuend not to be zero, minuend = subtrahend -> zero flag set).

Am I right with my assumptions or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You're assuming the CPU is negating and adding.  What makes you think that this is a valid assumption?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm that is how subtract is implemented in logic.  It is not a negate and add though you invert an operand and the carry in.  equivalent to a negate but that subtle difference.  (negate itself requires an addition step, so why do two additions to do a subtract when you can do it almost for free with one)

Comment: @old_timer - Why couldn't a CPU use [subtractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractor) logic?

Comment: you answered your own question with that link.

Comment: x86's CF result from a subtract is set when borrow happened.  There are multiple ways the hardware could make this happen.

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition is almost correct.  Here is the missing bit: subtraction can be implemented through addition by complementing both the minuend, the incoming carry (0 for `sub`, becoming 1) and the outgoing carry.  When you subtract 0 from some number, what is added is `0xffffffff` (assuming a 32 bit CPU) and a 1 from the inverted carry.  Thus, we actually add `0x100000000`, setting the outgoing carry (i.e. clearing the outgoing borrow).  This is the difference to your model where 0 would be added, not setting the outgoing carry (i.e. setting the outgoing borrow),

Comment: note not all architectures invert the carry out into a borrow.

Comment: @old_timer Sure, but OP specifically asked about x86.

Comment: yep, your answer was phrased generic not x86 specific, implying this is how it works everywhere, which it doesnt, no need to add confusion while clearing up confusion.